# what do "this" means in multithreading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
t=new Thread(this,"clocky");
t.start();
```

This is the way of creating a new thread but I don't get why this is used.

Comment: Correction: This is **a** way of creating a new thread. See [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Lets start looking at java doc. You are actually calling this constructor

`public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`

[java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String)) says

> **target** - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is
>   started. If null, this thread's run method is invoked.
>
> **name** - the name of the new thread

Here `this` refers the current object of the class where you are calling it, as it is in elsewhere in java. And I am sure your that class implements `Runnable` and overrides `run()` method. Thats how constructor parameter matches.

Comment: Minor typo on last word: *matches*.

Comment: `this` is not a reference to the current _class_, it's a reference to the object that is being constructed.  Read about  [_safe publication_](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/) to learn why you should never give the `this` pointer to another thread from within a constructor.

Comment: yes, actually I meant that. grammartically that is the real thing. edited @jameslarge

Answer (score 1):

Means that you are using the current object `run()` method, from the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, as this thread main/starting method.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look**

[Multithread Basics](https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java)

**Simple Example**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


    Thread threadOne = new Thread(new Class_1(),"Class_1");
    Thread threadTwo = new Thread(new Class_2(), "Class_2");


    threadOne.run();  //This run calls run in Class_1
    threadTwo.run();  //This run calls run in Class_2


}

}

class Class_1 implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Class_1 run method");
}
}

class Class_2 implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Class_2 run method");
}
}
```

**Output**

```
Class_1 run method
Class_2 run method
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be implementing the *Runnable* interface in your current class and initializing the thread by passing the current runnable object using **this** keyword inside the constructor of your class.

It must be calling the *run* method while creating the instance of the runnable class like the below sample.

```
public class Nool implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    public Nool() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Nool");
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("NOOL");
    }

}
```

I hope the explanation helps you.

Comment: Except, it's a _Really Bad Idea_ to give a thread a reference to some object before the constructor of that object has returned.  (I.e., before the object has been [_safely published_](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/))

Comment: @jameslarge I can't understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: The constructor of your `Nool` class gives `this` to a new thread.  `this` is a reference to the object that the constructor has not yet finished constructing.  That's bad because there's been no synchronization between the threads when the new thread starts.  Without synchronization, there are not guarantees about when (if ever) one thread will see changes made by a different thread.  Even though the `thread.start()` is the very last thing that your constructor does, it's possible for the new thread to see the object in an unconstructed state.

Comment: @jameslarge That's not quite accurate: [A call to `start` on a thread *happens-before* any action in the started thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)